# User Defined Function runs but spits out #VALUE error

Tags: vba, excel

**ANSWER: Stupid, stupid, stupid errors. Firstly I put `category as Single` when it should have been `category as String`. Then I misused the Cells function because I thought it wouldn't accept incrementing in A1 format. Lastly, my if statement was drawing from the wrong worksheet. Should have been the "Gear Chance Effect Stats" sheet.**

Sorry if this is a simple error. My VBA training was very basic and I am trying to practice by making a program for my game.

My function is below. I couldn't even do a simple if category matches "FastAtk", which it should, then the function equals 1 (or 0 if it doesn't match). Still returned #VALUE error. My blood is boiling lol. I need to lay down.

Categories that can be read from table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDJwi.jpg

Table - Effects where instances of category are counted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjY5f.jpg

```
Function MaxGearCalc(category As Single) As Single

cat_reg = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("CharacterBuild").Range("C6:G8"), category)
cat_plus = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("CharacterBuild").Range("C6:G8"), category & "+")

For i = 1 To 18 Step 1
    If category = Worksheets("CharacterData").Cells(1, Column(i + 1)) Then
        max_reg = Worksheets("Gear Chance Effect Stats").Cells(57, Column(i + 1))
        max_plus = Worksheets("Gear Chance Effect Stats").Cells(57, Column(i + 2))
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

MaxGearCalc = cat_plus * max_plus + cat_reg * max_reg

End Function
```

Comment: `Column` is not a thing - maybe you meant `Columns(i+1)` but you probably just need `i+1` there

Comment: `category As Single` means category can only hold numbers. Your categories appear to be strings so try `category As String`

Comment: Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of your module; declare all your variables so that your code compiles again, and then come back and [edit] this post if there's still a problem.

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you. I am using A1 format versus R1C1, so I was trying the columns function. Is that incorrect?

Comment: You have a typo there, but if you use `Columns(i+1)` that would return the whole column, whereas I think you only mean to reference a single cell.  A1 vs. R1C1 has no impact here.  Cells() expects either two numbers or a number and a letter - eg. `Cells(2,2)` or `Cells(2, "B")`

Comment: BTW if you call your function from a sub instead of from the worksheet you will see this issue as the code will break on the error, unlike calling it from the worksheet where it just returns #VALUE

Comment: @TimWilliams wow very insightful! Thank you so much. You have no idea how much I appreciate your help and the help of others on this site as well.

Comment: @Mat'sMug so option explicit makes you define ALL variables? Very nice. Helps me be a little less of an idiot. That should help a lot down the road.

Comment: @barrowc I knew I was missing something stupid. Glossed right over that! Thank you very much for your help! You were so polite about my idiot mistake

Comment: Whenever you write a User Defined Function which you want to call from a worksheet cell, make sure ALL cell references the function needs are passed as arguments to the function. Do not include ANY fixed Range or Cells references in the UDF.

Comment: @jkpieterse Thank you for your input! I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you mean. Would you mind delving further into details? Like which part conflicts with what you are saying and what can I do differently?

Comment: @jkpieterse I feel like you are talking about `cat_reg` and `cat_plus`.  My guess is that you are saying to make another argument that is a range, where the user can select the range. If the range is always `"C6:G8"` would it be bad to keep that fixed in the function?

Comment: Yes. One reason: if anyone decides to insert a column or row (or delete) the address in your UDF will be wrong but if used as an argument in the function they will be adjusted by Excel. And I also refer to the other ones. None should be hardcoded.